# Is there a way to get a Github tab in Microsoft Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, github, model-view-controller, package

I watched a video on Microsoft visual studio youtube channel on how to work with git and github. When the user opened their visual studio program. I see the normal solution and team explorer. They also have a github tab. I wanted to know of there was a package that needed to be added. I downloaded just about every package that has to do with github extensions but with no luck. Any help would be appreciated. Here the link to the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9ITVx4VvkcI timestamp 5:27 for better clarification. Here is a screenshot  of the github feature I do not have higlighted.

[image: Here is the image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

5:04 in video, the screen of VS2019 installer, see on the right, it's an individual component to install:

> Github Extension for Visual Studio

If that fails install it from here: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GitHub.GitHubExtensionforVisualStudio

[image]

Then click View menu > Other Windows > GitHub:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I did install the individual component to install from 5:04 in video. Unfortunately, I still wasn't able to get the github tab.

Comment: I now got it. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Test can you please tick the Holo checkbox to the left of my answer, it'll give you a few points and let everyone know it's solved. Good luck!

Comment: I was able to see git tab after I updated my Visual Studio 2019 Preview to version 16.11.11